# Sync other branch when amending commit in current branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase, git-amend

I have to branches, A and B:

```
1-2-3
  ^ ^
  A B
```

Say I want to amend commit 2, so I checkout branch A and do `git commit --amend`.
Now my graph looks like this:

```
1--2'   [A]
 \-2-3  [B]
```

Is there a way to also automatically update branch B (in case there are no conflicts) so that my graph looks like

```
1-2'-3
  ^  ^
  A  B
```

I know that I can do `git checkout B && git rebase A` and use `git rebase --skip`, but is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

That hypothetical expected situation

```
1-2'-3
  ^  ^
  A  B
```

*cannot* happen, since `3` has `2` as its parent forever.

In git, "changing the parent of a commit" is impossible, what you *can* do is to create a new commit with the new parent (which happens during rebases and cherry-picks, and is often symbolized like your above `2'`).

**Rebasing, as you considered, is the typical way to handle this.** *(And no, there's no really quicker/easier way.)*

---

A more accurate description of your end result after your rebase :

```
1---2---3 <<< not referenced anymore, 2 and 3 are candidates for garbage collection
 \
  2' <<< A
   \
    3' <<< B <<< HEAD
```

Comment: It would, however, make sense to have a Git command that worked by checkout out commit `3` via branch `B`, then did a rebase that copied `2` to `2'` and `3` to `3'` and then *moved both branch names*. I tried to write this command, but it's *really hard* to get it right for all possible cases. Sometimes you want `A` to move and sometimes you don't. Sometimes there are commits *on* `A` past `2`. And so on...

Comment: I'm not even near the point where writing such a command becomes a possibility, but yes it's what I tried to convey with my vague *there's no really quicker/easier way*. Writing your own commands is not what I would describe as "easy" :-)